# Let $K$ be a number field and $O_K$ be ring of integers of $K$. Let $I$ be fractional ideal of $O_K$ which satisfies $I⊂O_K$ and $I^{-1}⊂O_K$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, algebraic-number-theory

Let  $K$ be a number field and $O_K$ be ring of integers of $K$.
Let $I$ be fractional ideal of $O_K$ which satisfies $I⊂O_K$ and $I^{-1}⊂O_K$. Then I want to prove $I=O_K$.Does this hold in general ? Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We have that $II^{-1} = O_K$. If both $I$ and $I^{-1}$ are contained in $O_K$, they are both ideals of $O_K$. If either is proper ideal of $O_K$, then their product is a proper ideal. So we must have $I = O_K$.

Comment: I had to think about why the third sentence is true, but I see it now. The product of two (or any number of) ideals is contained in the intersection of the two ideals, so the product of two proper ideals is indeed again a proper ideal.

Comment: @RP_: precisely! : )

Answer (score 1):

I guess the easiest thing would be to use the fact that in a Dedekind domain, every ideal can be written as a product of prime ideals in a unique way. We can write $I=\prod_{i \in I} P_i^{e_i}$ and $I^{-1}=\prod_{i \in I} P_i^{f_i}$, with all $e_i,f_i \geq 0$. Then $II^{-1}=O_K=\prod_{i \in I} P_i^{e_i+f_i}$. By unique factorization, we must have $e_i+f_i=0$ for all $i$, and therefore $e_i=f_i=0$ for all $i$.